# Can jQuery find elements before they're appended to the document?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm finding that HTML/DOM created via $() is not searchable until it's been appended to the document. Is this expected, or am I doing something wrong?

```
var html = "<div data-test='test'>testdiv</div>";

// Convert HTML string to an orphaned JQ DOM object
var dom = $(html);

// Search orphaned DOM for element(s) with the specified attr
var found1 = dom.find('[data-test]');
// --> found1.length == 0, why not 1?

// Now insert the orphaned DOM into the document
$('#content').html(dom);

// And now JQ will find the desired elements
var found2 = $('[data-test]');
// --> found2.length is 1, as expected
```

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/5dVc8/

**UPDATE**

It turns out that my original question was too simplistic.

@RocketHazmat's answer did indeed address what I had originally asked, but when I went to use that info I found that I wasn't specific enough.

It turns out that I need to match elements in the root AND/OR the children. Seems that, as  @RocketHazmat says, .find() matches children but .filter() only matches the root.

Here's updated snippet and a new fiddle to demo:

```
var html = "<div data-test='test1'>";     // Root
html += "<div data-test='test2'></div>";  // Child
html += "</div>";

// Convert HTML string to an orphaned JQ DOM object
var dom = $(html);

// Search orphaned DOM object for element(s) with the specified attr
// (We'll find none)
var found1 = dom.find('[data-test]');
$('#count1').html('count1='+found1.length+", val="+found1.attr('data-test'));

// Search orphaned DOM object for element(s) with the specified attr
// (We'll find none)
var found2 = dom.filter('[data-test]');
$('#count2').html('count2='+found2.length+", val="+found2.attr('data-test'));


// Now append the orphaned DOM to the document
$('#content').html(dom);

// And now JQ will find the desired elements
var found3 = $('[data-test]');
$('#count3').html('count3='+found3.length);
```

and the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XyDSg/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
var found1 = dom.filter('[data-test]');
```

`.find()` searches all *children*.  In your case, `'[data-test]'` is the "root" element, so you need `.filter()`.

UPDATE:

You can wrap your HTML in another `<div>`, then `.find()` would work as you want.

```
var dom = $('<div>'+html+'</div>');
var found1 = dom.find('[data-test]');
```

Just remember to remove it when you append it elsewhere.

```
$('#content').html(dom.html()); // This "removes" the parent `<div>`
```

Comment: Seems like .filter() only finds the root... is there any way to search BOTH the root an children? Here's an updated fiddle demoi'ing this: http://jsfiddle.net/XyDSg/1/

Comment: @dlchambers: Yes, `.filter()` finds the root (or roots, such as when doing `$('div').filter(...)`).  I don't think there's a built-in way to search both.

Comment: @dlchambers: You could wrap your HTML in a "fake" `<div>` then use `.find()`.  `var dom = $('<div>'+html+'</div>'); var found1 = dom.find(...)`.

Comment: I solved it with a combo of the two methods. I created a helper function __process() then call __process(dom.filter(selector)) then call __process(dom.find(selector)). Less elegant than a single JQ call, but it works!

Answer (score -1):

You can create the div as a jQuery object

```
var myDiv = jQuery('<div/>', {
                    'data-test' : 'test'
                  });
```

And then append it anywhere eg

```
$('#myElement').append(myDiv);
```

The beauty of this is you can create the div and then manipulate it like any jquery object.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.  Plus he's already making a jQuery object when he does `$(html)`.